# Django ModelForm with ManyToManyField showing all possible objects

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many, modelform

I need your help with this. I tried to find the solution for a couple of days, but no luck so far.  Here is the set up:

There can be several projects, tasks and people can be assigned to projects, a person can be assigned to several tasks, and the same task can be assigned to different people. No problems so far...

When I try to show a form for a specific task (which is assigned to 1 project), it shows all people from all projects, but I need to see people only from the project associated with the selected task.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField('Person Name',max_length=50)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person_name 

class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField('Task Name',max_length=50)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name 

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('task_name','people',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strategy**: Dynamically limiting the queryset to allowed `People`-objects at form instantiation.

I also wouldn't omit the `project`field in the form since it will be required when you save the form. A better way is hiding the field and passing an [initial value dynamically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) to it.

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        widgets = {'project': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Form requires a project, so assert it is instantiated with a valid initial value:
        assert 'initial' in kwargs and 'project' in kwargs['initial'] and type(kwargs['initial']['project'] is Project)
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        project = kwargs['initial']['project']
        self.fields['people'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(project=project)

# Instantiate the form. 'my_project' has to be a Project-instance
my_taskform = TaskForm(initial={'project': my_project})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very helpful.